# Sorting a List of Objects based on a List of other Objects having common fields

Tags: java, list, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I have a random unsorted `ArrayList` of objects `A`, which have common fields with object `B`, and another `ArrayList` of objects `B`.

I want to order the elements in `ArrayList` of objects `A` based on those common fields.

*My code:*

```java
public class Protocol {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Protocol [referenceName=" + referenceName + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    private String referenceName = "314596";
    private String value = "12345";

    public Protocol(String referenceName, String value) {
        super();
        this.referenceName = referenceName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getReferenceName() {
        return referenceName;
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

```java
public class Sensor {

    private String referenceName = "314596";
    private String value = "12345";

    public Sensor(String referenceName, String value) {
        this.referenceName = referenceName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getReferenceName() {
        return referenceName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sensor [referenceName=" + referenceName + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Protocol protocol1 = new Protocol("31543678", "09866546534");
        Protocol protocol2 = new Protocol("343443678", "09866567897874334");
        Protocol protocol3 = new Protocol("41563678", "0663846546534");
        Protocol protocol4 = new Protocol("9876543", "009876546546534");

        List<Protocol> protocolList = new ArrayList<>();
        protocolList.add(protocol4);
        protocolList.add(protocol1);
        protocolList.add(protocol3);
        protocolList.add(protocol2);
        
        for (int i =0; i < protocolList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(protocolList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************************************");

        Sensor sensor1 = new Sensor("31543678", "09866546534");
        Sensor sensor2 = new Sensor("343443678", "09866567897874334");
        Sensor sensor3 = new Sensor("41563678", "0663846546534");
        Sensor sensor4 = new Sensor("9876543", "009876546546534");
        
        List<Sensor> sensorList = new ArrayList<>();
        sensorList.add(sensor1);
        sensorList.add(sensor3);
        sensorList.add(sensor2);
        sensorList.add(sensor4);
        
        List<Sensor> sensorList1 = new ArrayList<>(sensorList);
        for(int i =0; i < sensorList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(sensorList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************************************");

        for (int i = 0; i < sensorList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < protocolList.size(); j++) {
                if (sensorList.get(i).getReferenceName() == protocolList.get(j).getReferenceName()) {
                    if (sensorList.get(i).getValue() == protocolList.get(j).getValue()) {
                        sensorList1.set(j, sensorList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sensorList1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(sensorList1.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output :

```
Protocol [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Protocol [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Protocol [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Protocol [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
*******************************************************
Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
*******************************************************
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
```

Based on the common fields, I want to sort `ObjectBList` so that the sequence matches `ObjectAList`.

This logic works correctly, but I feel there might some **faster** or **easier** way to do this.

Only issue with the map approach is :

```
Given:
Protocol [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334, random=TEST]
Protocol [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534, random=TEST]
Protocol [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534, random=TEST]
Protocol [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534, random=TEST]
Protocol [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334, random=TEST]
Protocol [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334, random=TEST]

Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=67534567, value=66565656]

expected  output:
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=67534567, value=66565656]

Output:
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Sensor [referenceName=67534567, value=66565656]
Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
```

The issue is it's grouping the same objects at the end not really preserving the order for duplicates.

One more thing would it work in a case where:
protocols has suppose 4 fields instead of two referenceName and value as well as referenceName1 and value1. And Sensors has same as before two.
Example:
Protocol(String referenceName,String value,String referenceName1 and String value1)
And
Sensor(String referenceName,String value)

Sensor can match protocols with combination of (referenceName and value) or (referenceName1 and value1). Would it work if pass those two fields into getKey method? There will be always a match between sensors and protocols either on combination of (referenceName and value) or (referenceName1 and value1) bearing in mind that either of them can be null.

Comment: It would be nicer if you would share your attempt.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I updated the question with my attempt. I feel like there is easier or faster way to do this.

Comment: Never compare strings with `==`, always compare them with `equals`. (The actual problem can be solved in linear time and space by creating a map from the field value to the "sensor", then going through the "protocols", look up the "sensor" for that respective field value in the map, and put that sensor into a list. Apparently, there might be _two_ field values here, so you might need a `Pair` as the key, but that's a detail)

Comment: @AD27060 Good. Now, it's an interesting problem. `I feel there might some faster ... ` - That's right, we can make it faster. Your code is based on a brute-force approach and has a time complexity of **O(n ^ 2)**. It can be improved by indexing the positions of in the list of `Protocol` objects. I will share more details in a minute.

Answer (score 3):

> This logic works correctly but I feel there might some **faster** or easier way to do this.

Your current solution utilizes a *brute force* approach, repeatedly checking the position of every protocol (*which doesn't change*) multiple times, and has a time complexity of **O(n * m)**.

We can improve it by indexing the position of each protocol in a list.

#### UPDATE - Linear time solution

###### *(covers examples containing duplicates added with the recent question update)*

This solution is based on the ***simplest case solution*** provided earlier in this answer. And it would run in a linear time.

Current solution covers the following cases:

- list of sensors can be larger than the list of protocols;
- *duplicates* might appear in both lists;
- a *sensor* might have no matching pair in the list of *protocols*, and vice versa.

The *resulting list of sensors* expected to contain all *sensors* that have a matching pair, ordered accordingly to indices of their pairs in the *list of protocols*, and *sensors* having matching pair grouped at the end of the list accordingly to their initial order.

*Assumption for the case of duplicates* (based on the example data in the question):

- Let's consider there are `5` *sensors* and `2` *protocols* having the same properties. The `2` *sensors* would be ordered in accordance with the indices of `2` *protocols*. And the remained `3` *sensors* will be considered having no matching pair and would be placed at the end of the list.

In order to meet these conditions, *array of sensors* should be initialized to the maximum size of two lists. Some positions in the populated array could hold `null` values which have to be filtered.

As well as in the *simplest case solution* positions would be stored in the *map*.

To facilitate the ability to handle duplicates, we need to store all the positions of each *protocol* in a *queue*. So the map would be of type `Map<String,Queue<Integer>>`. And then while placing the *sensors* in to the array, required positions would be extracted from the queue one by one. If the queue is empty or there's no matching protocol (the call to the map will return `null`) then *sensors* would be added into a separate list which afterwards would be appended to the end of the resulting list.

*Implementation:*

Method responsible for creation of the map.

```
public static Map<String, Queue<Integer>> getPositions(List<Protocol> protocols) {

    Map<String, Queue<Integer>> positionByKey = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < protocols.size(); i++) {
        Protocol next = protocols.get(i);
        String key = getKey(next.getReferenceName(), next.getValue());
    
        positionByKey.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayDeque<>()).add(i);
    }
    return positionByKey;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Protocol> protocols =
        List.of(new Protocol("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Protocol("9876543", "009876546546534"),
                new Protocol("31543678", "09866546534"),
                new Protocol("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Protocol("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Protocol("343443678", "09866567897874334"));
    
    List<Sensor> sensors =
        List.of(new Sensor("31543678", "09866546534"),
                new Sensor("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Sensor("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Sensor("9876543", "009876546546534"),
                new Sensor("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Sensor("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Sensor("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Sensor("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Sensor("67534567", "66565656"));
    
    Map<String, Queue<Integer>> positionByKey = getPositions(protocols);

    Sensor[] orderedSensors = new Sensor[Math.max(sensors.size(), protocols.size())];
    List<Sensor> sensorsWithNoPair = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Sensor next : sensors) {
        String key = getKey(next.getReferenceName(), next.getValue());
        Queue<Integer> positions = positionByKey.get(key);
        
        if (positions == null || positions.isEmpty()) { // matching protocol doesn't exist at all, or we run out of indices in the queue
            sensorsWithNoPair.add(next);
            continue;
        }
        
        int position = positionByKey.get(key).remove();
        orderedSensors[position] = next;
    }

    List<Sensor> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Sensor next : orderedSensors) {
        if (next != null) result.add(next);
    }
    
    result.addAll(sensorsWithNoPair);
    // printing the result
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=9876543, value=009876546546534]
Sensor [referenceName=31543678, value=09866546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=343443678, value=09866567897874334]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=41563678, value=0663846546534]
Sensor [referenceName=67534567, value=66565656]
```

[*A link to the Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rto)

#### The simplest case

Let's start with the simplest case that corresponds to the example of data you've provided:

- list of `Protocol`s and list of `Sensor`s are of the same size;
- each *sensor* has a matching pair (by `referenceName` and `value`) in the list of *protocols*;
- each combination of the `referenceName` and `value` is unique.

In this case, sorting can be done in linear time **O(n)**.

We need a single iteration over the *list of protocols* to index the position of each *protocol*. We can store it in the map.

And for that we need an intermediate object that would be used as a key. The simplest approach to obtain the key is to concatenate the `referenceName` and `value`. A more generalized approach will be to use a *record* (or class) for that purpose. For now, I'll go with the simplest one - a map `Map<String,Integer>`, *index* of each *protocol* by *key*.

The next step is to order the *sensors* in accordance with the *map of indices*. We can create an array of length equal to the size of the *list of sensors*, and then iterate over the *list of sensors* by placing every *sensor* at a position retrieved from a *map*.

In order to turn the array of sensors into a list, we can use static method `List.of()` available with Java 9, or `Arrays.asList()` for earlier versions.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Protocol> protocols =
        List.of(new Protocol("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Protocol("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Protocol("31543678", "09866546534"),
                new Protocol("9876543", "009876546546534"));

    List<Sensor> sensors =
        List.of(new Sensor("31543678", "09866546534"),
                new Sensor("343443678", "09866567897874334"),
                new Sensor("41563678", "0663846546534"),
                new Sensor("9876543", "009876546546534"));

    Sensor[] orderedSensors = new Sensor[sensors.size()];
    Map<String, Integer> positionByKey = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < protocols.size(); i++) {
        Protocol next = protocols.get(i);
        positionByKey.put(getKey(next.getReferenceName(), next.getValue()), i);
    }

    for (Sensor next: sensors) {
        int position = positionByKey.get(getKey(next.getReferenceName(), next.getValue()));
        orderedSensors[position] = next;
    }
    
    List<Sensor> result = List.of(orderedSensors); // or for Java 8 and earlier Arrays.asList(orderedSensors);
}

public static String getKey(String first, String second) {
    return first + ":" + second;
}
```

#### General case

General case solution doesn't require any assumption, i.e. it should be capable to deal with the following scenarios:

- the sizes of the lists might be *unequal*;
- combinations of the `referenceName` and `value` are not guaranteed to be unique;
- a *sensor* might have no matching pair in the list of *protocols*.

The overall approach remains the same: we need to index the position of each *protocol* and store it in a *map*.

But we will not access this *map* directly, instead it will be used by the *comparator*. And in this solution, a custom object will be used as a *key*. To avoid the necessity to override `equals` and `hashCode` it's implemented as a Java 16 [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html):

```
public record Key(String first, String second) {
    
    public Key(Sensor item) {
        this(item.getReferenceName(), item.getValue());
    }
    
    public Key(Protocol item) {
        this(item.getReferenceName(), item.getValue());
    }
}
```

To create a *comparator*, first we have to build a *map*, and then we can make use of the static method [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)):

```
public static Comparator<Sensor> compareByKey(List<Protocol> base) {
    
    Map<Key, Integer> orderByKey = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < base.size(); i++) {
        Protocol next = base.get(i);
        orderByKey.put(new Key(next), i);
    }
    
    return Comparator.comparingInt((Sensor item) ->
        orderByKey.getOrDefault(new Key(item), -1)); // sensors that have no matching pair in the list of protocols will be grouped at the beginning of the resulting list
}
```

The main method will require only one line to do the sorting because the comparator does all the heavy lifting. And because now we are dealing with the sorting, the time complexity would be *linear-logarithmic*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Protocol> protocols = // initializing the list of protocols
    List<Sensor> sensors =     // initializing the list of sensors
    
    List<Sensor> orderedSensors = new ArrayList<>(sensors); // making a defensive copy, omit this line it's not required to preserve the unsorted list of sensors

    orderedSensors.sort(compareByKey(protocols);
}
```

*Note:* that this approach can be generalized further by making use of generic type parameters, so that it would be possible to apply it to any pair of objects. That would require making the `Key` class generic, and the method responsible for generating the *comparator* in order to be able to extract the needed attributes from an arbitrary object should be provided with a couple of *functions*.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of your approach. The issue is when there are duplicates, it's not sorting as required. All duplicates have been grouped together. Any ideas to fix that??

Comment: @AD27060 Sure, that doable. Now, duplicated *sensors* get grouped according to the position of the first occurrence of the *protocol* having the same values. To change this behavior, we need to store all the positions of each *protocol* in a queue. So the map would be of type `Map<String,Queue<Integer>>`. And then while reordering the *sensors* required positions would be extracted from the queue one by one.

Comment: @AD27060 I had a closer look at the new example of data you've provided. Please correct  me if I'm getting something wrong. You expect the lists to be **not** equal in size. All the *sensors* that have a matching pair in the list of *protocols* should occupy the same positions in the resulting list. If the list of *sensors* is large, all extra sensors should be placed in the end of the resulting list, ordered accordingly to their initial positions. Or it just a coincidence that you've ordered them this way?

Comment: @AD27060 What shall we do with *sensors* that have no matching pair? Can you please add all this information to the question.

Comment: The sensors with no matching pair should go to end of list. At least one that match with protocol have to be in same order. Thanks!!

Comment: @AD27060 I've updated the answer with the version that is capable to handle the duplicates runs in a linear time. I've tested it against the new example you've provided, it produces the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The algorithm works as expected. But I have updated the scenario with slight modification. Sensors can match protocols on combination of (refName and  value) or (refName1 and value1) where each of these fields can be null for protocols either first combination or second. Can the following approach work if i just pass four fields into getKey method instead of two?

Comment: @AD27060 Well, it's highly advisable to avoid making changes in the question that would invalidate the existing answers (which is the case now). And ideally, the problem statement should be narrow-focused and clear (currently there's a mixture of different data-samples and requirements).  The easier it's to digest the question and its answers, the more likely it can be useful to someone with the similar problem. This site is famous for its helpful answers, and it's important to keep both *questions* and *answers* in such a state so that other people can benefit from them.

Comment: @AD27060 That's why I kindly suggest you to open a new question that would target this *updated requirement* and edit the current question so that it would reflect the previous version of problem statement. Specifically, I advise you to leave only the last data sample (*with duplicates*) and provide a detailed explanation on how the resulting list of *sensors* should be ordered (*you can use as a template the description from the answer*).

Comment: @AD27060 **Note**, that a new question should be *self-contained* and *elaborate*, i.e. it should be provided with the *code*, a *data sample*, and a verbal *expiation* on how the list of sensors should be ordered and how `(refName and value)` could match `(refName1 and value1)` (*which currently is not clear*). You can place a link to this question into a new one, but it should contain enough data by itself to be answered. Also, [*see*](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1):

The key is obtaining order strategy from protocolList

1.Implement equals & hashCode for Protocol, e.g.,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Protocol)) return false;
    Protocol protocol = (Protocol) o;
    return Objects.equals(getReferenceName(), protocol.getReferenceName()) && Objects.equals(getValue(), protocol.getValue());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getReferenceName(), getValue());
}
```

2.Sort sensorList using custom Comparator

```
sensorList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(one -> protocolList.indexOf(new Protocol(one.getReferenceName(), one.getValue()))));
```

P.S.hashCode() is optional if u don't put Protocol into hash collections

Comment: Method `indexOf()` has a cost **O(n)**. It performs the iteration over the list as well as the original code, therefore this solution would not be any faster than the code provided by OP. The time complexity of this code **O(n ^ m log m)** because of poorly implemented comparator. Time complexity of the original code **O(n * m)**. I.e. in fact it would be slower.

Comment: Forgot to consider performance...Thx